# Lombok installer popup prevents me from running build

Tags: java, macos, gradle, intellij-idea, lombok

A very strange thing starts happening today. I am running building my java gradle app locally using

`gradle clean install`

And all of a sudden the terminal halts

```
> :installLombok
```

and this pops up:

[image: popup]

So what is going on? How can I stop this from happening?
I don't use Eclipse, why is asking me where is Eclipse?

Some other details:

- OS: MacOs Mojave 10.14.3
- IntelliJ version: 2018.3.2(Ultimate)
- Lombok Plugin version for intelliJ: v0.23-2018.3
- Gradle version: 5.2.1

Any ide what this could be?

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle` file please? Most probably you have a task called `installLombok` there that needs to be removed.